# Stream video from user encrypted remote file

Tags: swift, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

The following situation: The user encrypts a video with AES-CBC (for now) with keys known only to the user and uploads the encrypted file to S3. I now want to play this video file using as little bandwidth as possible. My first approach was to use the .m3u8 file to play the video, which didn't work.

So the question is: how to stream a video that has been encrypted by the user with keys that only the user knows?